# Keyboard in flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I'm trying to prevent keyboard show when I click Textinput field on my device.
I use Textinput only to show some text and for click event (to push a view).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `needsSoftKeyboard="false"` instead.

**flash.display.InteractiveObject.needsSoftKeyboard(value:Boolean):void**
Specifies whether a virtual keyboard (an on-screen, software keyboard) should display when this InteractiveObject instance receives focus.By default, the value is false and focusing an InteractiveObject instance does not raise a soft keyboard. If the needsSoftKeyboard property is set to true, the runtime raises a soft keyboard when the InteractiveObject instance is ready to accept user input

Answer (score 0):

```
on Application Creation Complete cc()

private function cc():void{
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    addEventListener("softKeyboardActivating", fun);
}
private function fun(event:Event):void{
        event.preventDefault();
    trace("softKeyboardActivate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just disable the TextInput field whilst putting a group around the input with an ID that deals with the click event.

```
<s:HGroup id="ID" click="Click_Eventhandler(event)">
    <s:TextInput enabled="false"/>
</s:HGroup>
```